# How does command substitution work with find?

Tags: macos, shell, unix, find

I have the following command

`` find . -name "*.tiff" -exec echo `basename -s .tiff {}` \; ``

I expect this to print all my .tiff-files without their file extensions. What I get is

```
./file1.tiff
./file2.tiff
...
```

The command,

`find . -name "*.tiff" -exec basename -s .tiff {} \;`

does yield

```
file1
file2
...
```

Is this not supposed to be the input of echo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The content of the backticks is executed *before* the find command - yielding just the placeholder `{}`, which is used in the find command line - hence your result.  You can always use `set -x` to examine what the shell is up to.

Comment: I'm trying to convert a batch of images using tiff2ps, any ideas?

Comment: @Steinbitglis, try : `for i in \`ls -R *.tiff\`; do tiff2ps $i > \`basename $i .tiff\`.ps; done` (not tested)

Answer (score 1):

Use single-quote characters (') instead of backticks (`) - putting a command in backticks causes it to be executed and replaced by its output in your command. 
Also, modify the command to get rid of the `echo`, like this:

```
find . -name "*.tiff" -exec 'basename -s .tiff {}' \;
```

This will execute `basename` on each found file.